# Парсинг текста + ссылки, встроенной в текст

Tags: парсер

Суть в том, что надо получить название заголовка (С чем я успешно справился), и получить ссылку, которая находится в тексте ()

[image: То, что надо запарсить]

````
    hot_news_url = 'https://ria.ru/location_rossiyskaya-federatsiya/'
    headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}
    full_page = requests.get(hot_news_url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
    convert = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'list-item__title', 'class': 'color-font-hover-only', })
    news_all = str(convert[0].text)```
````

Answer (score 0):

`a` - html тег, с помощью метода `get` получаем ссылку отправляя параметр `href` в метод

пример для понимания принципа работы:

```
html = <a href="/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="" rel="tag">парсер</a>

a = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

link = a.get('href')
text = a.text

print(link) # /questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80
print(text) # парсер
```

решение ваше проблемы:

```
news_all = convert[0].text, convert[0].get('href')
print(news_all) # ('Дипломаты встретились с задержанными в Белоруссии россиянами ', 'https://ria.ru/20200801/1575252234.html')
```

Comment: Так, а как мне это правильно добавить в код мой, чтобы находилась именно с этим текстом?

Comment: @БогданЯрулин добавил минимальный пример, основываясь на этом измените свой код

Comment: Вместо нужной мне ссылки, выводится None

Comment: @БогданЯрулин значит атрибута href нет в вашем теге, распечатайте тег и посмотрите что он из себя представляет вообще

Comment: Сверху есть скриншот, на котором всё видно. В теге находится текст, с ссылкой

Comment: @БогданЯрулин уверены, что все правильно делаете? добавил для вашего решения и все выводит что надо

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть готовый код, ибо сам я что-то не очень понимаю

Comment: @БогданЯрулин в конце ответа дополнил же